# Why is the second example not a Simplicial Complex?

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff, simplex

This is my first encounter of simplex and simplicial complex, hence I am not very sure about the concepts.

In the definition of [Simplicial Complex](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimplicialComplex.html)
, I am not sure why is the second picture not a simplicial complex?

The intersection of the two triangles is a line, which is also a "face" isn't it?

Comment: Umm, point 2 in the definition? The intersection of the second pair is not a face of either of them (which are the lines joining the vertices).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stochasticboy321 said, in the second example the intersection of the two simplices is a *proper subset* of the faces of each of them.  A proper subset of a face is not a face!